# Detect 'type' of self referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's model and its two join tables:

```
class Discourse < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :forum
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :impressions

    has_many :discourse_replies
    has_many :replies, through: :discourse_replies

    has_many :reply_retorts
    has_many :retorts, through: :reply_retorts
end

class DiscourseReply < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :discourse
    belongs_to :reply, class_name: 'Discourse', foreign_key: 'reply_id'
end

class ReplyRetort < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :reply
    belongs_to :retort, class_name: 'Discourse', foreign_key: 'retort_id'
end
```

In the `Discourse` model, how can I detect when the model is a `reply` or a `retort`?

Something along these lines:

```
class Discourse < ActiveRecord::Base
    # removed relationships for brevity       

    def is_discourse?
        # if instance is a discourse, return true else false
    end


    def is_reply?
        # if instance is a reply, return true else false
    end

    def is_retort?
        # if instance is a retort, return true else false
    end
end
```

So that I can do the following:

```
2.0.0p247 :004 > discourse = Discourse.create
 => #

2.0.0p247 :001 > reply = discourse.replies.create
 => #

2.0.0p247 :005 > retort = reply.retorts.create
 => #

2.0.0p247 :006 > retort_retort = retort.retorts.create
 => #

2.0.0p247 :007 > discourse.is_discourse? #=> true
2.0.0p247 :007 > reply.is_reply? #=> true
2.0.0p247 :007 > retort.is_retort? #=> true
2.0.0p247 :007 > retort_retort.is_retort? #=> true
2.0.0p247 :007 > retort_retort.is_reply? #=> false
2.0.0p247 :007 > retort_retort.is_discourse? #=> false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Discourse < ActiveRecord::Base
    # removed relationships for brevity       

    def is_discourse?
        !is_reply? && !is_retort?
    end

    def is_reply?
        DiscourseReply.where(reply_id: id).any?
    end

    def is_retort?
        ReplyRetort.where(retort_id: id).any?
    end
end
```

I guess that's what I'd do. Because I think that the presence of join table record is the only thing that characterize the type of a Discourse.

Comment: The `is_retort?` method raises a `undefined constant Discourse::DiscourseRetort` error. Why do you think this would this occur?

Comment: Because I meant `ReplyRetort` ^^.